# Environments and lazy evaluation: getting rid of symbols and getting values

Tags: r, nse

I am trying to wrap my head around a problem I ran into that I think largely revolves around environments, lazy evaluation and issues related to these things. I have a main function (`foo1` below) that in my actual use case is quite extensive. For this reason I am trying to provide some wrapper functions (`foo2` and `foo3`) that modify specific elements of the main function.

My problem is that I in the end don't obtain actual values, but I obtain symbols. Can someone provide some guidance as to what I need to with environments and what not to get this sorted?

Here's my MWE:

```
foo1 <- function(foo, a, b, c=1, d=1) {
  if (!missing(foo)) {
    mcall <- as.list(match.call())[-(1:2)]
    call_names <- names(mcall)
    foo <- foo[-which(names(foo) %in% call_names)]
    foo <- c(foo, mcall)
  } else {
    foo <- list(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)
  }
  return(foo)
}

foo2 <- function(a, b) {
  foo1(a=a, b=b)
}

foo3 <- function(foo, c, d) {
  foo1(foo, c=c, d=d)
}

f <- foo2(a=1, b=1) 
f <- foo3(f, c=2, d=2)
str(f)

> str(f)
List of 4
 $ a: num 1
 $ b: num 1
 $ c: symbol c
 $ d: symbol d
```

Here I want `c` and `d` to be equal to `2`, but they are symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `match.call`, it prevents evaulation of the parameters. If you want to evaluate the parameters, then you need to explicitly do so. For example

```
foo1 <- function(foo, a, b, c=1, d=1) {
  if (!missing(foo)) {
    mcall <- as.list(match.call())[-2]
    mcall[[1]] <- quote(list)
    mcall <- eval(as.call(mcall))
    call_names <- names(mcall)
    foo <- foo[-which(names(foo) %in% call_names)]
    foo <- c(foo, mcall)
  } else {
    foo <- list(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)
  }
  return(foo)
}
```

This turns the call to `foo1` into a call to `list()` and evaluates the result. Another option would be just to use `mget()` with the variables in the local environment that you want to capture. This will trigger the evaulation

```
foo1 <- function(foo, a, b, c=1, d=1) {
  if (!missing(foo)) {
    mlist <- mget(intersect(setdiff(ls(), "foo"), names(match.call())))
    call_names <- names(mlist)
    foo <- foo[-which(names(foo) %in% call_names)]
    foo <- c(foo, mlist)
  } else {
    foo <- list(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)
  }
  return(foo)
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!